# How to add a rewrite condition to only pass URL's with one folder depth?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that needs to only be applied to urls that go no further in depth than 1 folder

```
example.com/a  >> rewrite me
```

AND NOT

```
example.com/a/b  >> don't rewrite me
```

So I only need to rewrite urls with a depth of 1. Greater depth is allowed but needs to go through unaltered.

How would i do that doing a Mod_Rewrite condition statement? And where can I have my personal rewrite rule written.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Matches URLs which are equal to: "", "<text>", or "<text>/"
# if it matches, the rewrite engine does not attempt to match any more patterns
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/?$ - [L]

# If the above doesn't match, meaning it's depth is more than one,
# it forbids the content from being delivered
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: can you please explain what each line does, thank you. And where would my rewrite statement go?

Comment: @Mohammad: Updated my answer. Hopefully that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks Tim, maybe my question was misleading though I require redirecting content that is one folder at most in depth, and the other urls are not rewritten but displayed. I believe your rewrite rule only prohibits my system to allow one dept urls to be requested while I only need to redirect them not to ban anything else. Thank you!

Comment: @Mohammad: Replace the `-` in the first rule with your rewrite pattern, and remove the 2nd rule entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I was just playing around with an expression like this.

`RewriteRule ^[^\/]+$ - [L]`

I believe that's what you're talking about.